# Angular Firebase route Guard

Tags: firebase-authentication, angular-route-guards

I want to add some route guard based on Firebase auth `displayName` property.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  if ( firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName === 'student' ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

but this function is not working .

How to do this correctly?